# Helmet.js still using some headers even though they are disabled

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, helmet.js

im using helmet.js in an express server. When I try to use paypal buttons for transactions, I get this error:
[image]

I've already disabled that part of helmet.js in my code:

```js
app.use(
    helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: false,
        crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
        crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    }),
);
```

But, as you can see, a content security policy error still shows up.

How can I fully disable it?

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. When you load your page, do you still see the `Content-Security-Policy` header in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

My guess: your cache isn't being cleared, and if you clear it (often with Shift-Refresh), this will be fixed.

Comment: I am sure it's not a caching error, I have disabled cache while dev tools are open and I have even hosted it on different ports to make sure it's not caching. A lot of things would also be blocked by the default options of CSP (when CSP is enabled).

Comment: Hmm, okay. Do you still see the header if you remove all mentions of Helmet from your app? What's the value of the `Content-Security-Policy` header in your devtools?

Comment: Once I remove helmet, there are no Content Security Policy errors.

Here is a screenshot of the headers when I install helmet back: https://imgur.com/tiQFgF7

Comment: Those headers all look like they're in `www.sandbox.paypal.com` frames. In other words, I don't see a `Content-Security-Policy` header coming from `localhost`.

Comment: I am aware of that, the only problem is when I remove helmet.js it seems to work fine. Ill check the headers for www.sandbox.paypal.com without helmet.js later and I’ll let you know the output.

Comment: The Content-Security-Policy header seems to be the same: https://imgur.com/a/xrSOWyJ
The PayPal SDK is just creating a "secure browser" (basically another window) in order for people to put in their payment information. Does helmet have anything that may be blocking that?

Image of what PayPal does: https://imgur.com/a/dDn8IeH

Comment: I don't think Helmet should be blocking that if CSP is disabled. From your screenshot, I see no CSP header on localhost but I _do_ see them on `www.sandbox.paypal.com`. (Your second screenshot doesn't load for me.)

Comment: It shows the same headers as before…
Ill try testing it by disabling everything in helmet and then start enabling things.
Is there any other way I can contact you?

Comment: Yes. Feel free to [open an issue on the Helmet repo](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues) or email <helmet@evanhahn.com>.